# Single-Sign-On Authorization in microservice architecture

Tags: authentication, oauth, architecture, authorization, microservices

What is a good design for Single-Sign-On Authentication / Authorization microservice architecture?

**My thoughts:**

I need to build microservices for handling authentication and authroization with an Async interface through a messaging bus (RMQ or Kafka).

- The Authentication service could be the user-microservice which manages the identity of users (username, password, email)
- The Authorization service is responsible for:

  1. Providing the Auth-Token for users with allowed access-roles.
  2. Acting as SSO service.
  3. Authorizing other microservices so not everyone publishes a message to the bus will be heard.

I have done some reasearch, and found 2-legged OAuth is used sometimes for internal web/micro services. But since OAuth depends mainly on HTTP 301s, having HTTP calls internally I think it is an overhead for the internal systems.

Thanks!

Comment: For the authorization piece, you can use XACML. Micro-services lend themselves well to XACML because they have a well-defined contract.